# Understanding a step in a proof involving an empirical process (machine learning)

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, machine-learning, empirical-processes

I am unable to understand the apparently simple step that yield the display appearing before Lemma B.1. in page 12 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.08687.pdf) by Chernozhukov et al. (2016). In particular I fail to see how (2.1) implies the equation in the display.

You do not need to know anything besides:

1. the notation, which is summarized on top of the same page,
2. the fact that $\psi(w;\theta_{0},\eta)=0$ if and only if
   $\eta=\eta_{0}$,
3. the fact that $I_k ^c$ is conditioned upon in the computation, so that $\hat{\eta}_0 (I_k ^c)$ is not random (i.e. the integration addresses only the $w$ component).

Comment: Firefox is warning me about an expired certificate, and I cannot easily open the paper. In general, it is considered better to make questions self-contained, since off-site resources can move, may not be accessible (in the disability sense, or in the sense I just mentioned), and make it more difficult to search for this question.

Comment: Thank you. Due to the very narrow question it is difficult to make it completely self contained. However I have changed the link to Arxiv.org, which should be easier to browse.